# Combining two distributions to get a single one?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Consider the following experiment:

Let $X$ be a random variable which has a beta distribution with some fixed parameters.

Let $Y$ be a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $X$.

In other words, we have a two step process:
1) get a number $x \in [0,1]$ from a beta distribution
2) get a number $y \in \{0,1\}$ from a coin flip with heads probability $x$.

Is it possible to say how $y$ will be distributed (in terms of the beta distribution parameters, I suppose)?

Comment: One case, by simulation, may help: If X ~ BETA(2,3), then it seems Y ~ BERN(2/5).

Comment: @BruceET what was the Bernoulli parameter?

Comment: As above, $p = 2/5.$ In R: `w = replicate(10^5, rbinom(1, 1, rbeta(1, 2, 3))); mean(w==1)` returns 0.40052, likely accurate to 2 places. Change to BETA(5, 3) gives $p \approx 5/8$. [Not sure this is _exactly_ the Bayesian situation @qwr has in mind.]

Comment: @BruceET I think you're right since the answer I give is based on Bayesian updating while the question asks about a single data point? I'm not sure

Comment: _Toward a solution:_ Suppose $X$ can take the three values $0.2, 0.3, 0.5$ with equal probability, Then what is the Bernoulli parameter? `w = replicate(10^5, rbinom(1, 1, sample(c(.2,.3,.5), 1))); mean(w==1)`
returns 0.33351. Mixture of Bernoullis.

Comment: Simulations are not necessary here (and I am not sure to follow the relevance of the comments above or of the ansswer below, to the question asked): by hypothesis, $P(Y=1\mid X)=X$ hence $$P(Y=1)=E(P(Y=1\mid X))=E(X)=a/(a+b)$$ Since $P(Y=1)+P(Y=0)=1$, this suffices to prove that the distribution of $Y$ is Bernoulli with parameter $a/(a+b)$.

Comment: @Did Thank you. Is it always the case that this sort of process of using two distributions always "collapses" into some other distribution?

Comment: Please define mathematically "this sort of process" and "collapses".

Comment: @Did If $X$ is a rv from some distribution with fixed parameters, and $Y$ is is a rv variable from some distribution parametrized by $X$, can the distribution of $Y$ always be described in terms of some fixed parameters? (I think this is what I mean to ask...?)

Comment: @theQman Well, yes, in terms of CDF, if, for every $y$, $$P(Y\leqslant y\mid X)=g(y,X)$$ for some prescribed function $g$, then $$P(Y\leqslant y)=E(P(Y\leqslant y\mid X))=E(g(y,X))$$ hence, if $X$ has a PDF $f_X$, then $$P(Y\leqslant y)=\int_\mathbb Rg(y,x)f_X(x)dx$$

Answer (score -1):

Yes. This is a very common application of [Bayesian inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference). In fact the Wikipedia article for [prior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) has your exact example in the lede. The beta distribution is described as a *prior distribution*, and the Bernoulli distribution is described as a *sampling distribution*.

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254676/140662) is the answer to your question: with a $X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(a,b)$ prior and a $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(X)$ likelihood, the posterior distribution is $\operatorname{Beta}(a',b')$ where $a'$ is the number of successes observed and $b'$ is the number of failures observed.

On the first observation no data has been collected yet, so $a'=a$ and $b' = b$ and we just have $\operatorname{Beta}(a,b)$.  This is also because the expected value of Bernoulli distribution is just $p$.